# Get status when transaction is confirmend

Tags: anchor, web3.js

I want to implement an alert which shows up when the transaction i sent gets confirmed.
Like on raydium, where you get a alert when transaction is sent and confirmed.

Answer (score 2):

```
const tx = await some_tx();
await connection.confirmTransaction(tx);
console.log("Tx confirmed");
```